# Get json content from external file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

I'm trying to get the json content from an external file, (list.json), but all attempts have failed.
I have prototyped my code in Jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/ctmvcyy1/).

I think that the solution is very simple but I'm certainly doing something wrong.

Thank you for helping me!

```
    var json = {
    "lojas": [
        {
            "cidade": "New York",
            "uf": "RS",
            "unidades": [
                {
                    "nome": "Tribeca",
                    "logradouro": "Rua Ligula Amet, 30",
                },
                {
                    "nome": "Brooklyn",
                    "logradouro": "Av. Venenatis Dapibus, 200",
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "cidade": "São Paulo",
            "uf": "SP",
            "unidades": [
                {
                    "nome": "Centro",
                    "logradouro": "Av. Purus Fusce, 1003",
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "cidade": "Rio de Janeiro",
            "uf": "RJ",
            "unidades": [
                {
                    "nome": "Copacabana",
                    "logradouro": "Rua Malesuada, 120",
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};

$.each(json.lojas, function (i, lojas) {
    var siglas = '<li><a href="#' + lojas.uf + '">' + lojas.cidade + '</a></li>';


    var cidades = '<ul id="' + lojas.uf + '"class="cidades">';
        $.each(lojas.unidades, function (i, unidades) {
            cidades += '<li><p>'+ unidades.nome + '</p><p>' + unidades.logradouro + '</p></li>'; 
        });
    cidades += '</ul>';

    $(siglas).appendTo('#lista-siglas');
    $(cidades).appendTo('#lista-cidades');
});
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. The code that you provided seems to work without a problem. Is your question how to keep the same functionality, but move the JSON object definition into a separate .json file?

Comment: Is your code running on a webserver? Did you try jQuery `$.ajax`? http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Yes! It's working fine! But I want do load the json content from an external file like "list.json".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working plunkr:  http://plnkr.co/edit/d23lntczvQZMEfOXRPqW?p=preview

Simply do:

```
$.getJSON("lojas.json", function (json){
    $.each(json.lojas, function (i, lojas) {
      var siglas = '<li><a href="#' + lojas.uf + '">' + lojas.cidade + '</a></li>';


      var cidades = '<ul id="' + lojas.uf + '"class="cidades">';
      $.each(lojas.unidades, function (i, unidades) {
        cidades += '<li><p>'+ unidades.nome + '</p><p>' + unidades.logradouro + '</p></li>'; 
      });
      cidades += '</ul>';

      $(siglas).appendTo('#lista-siglas');
      $(cidades).appendTo('#lista-cidades');
    });
  });
```

Note that in order for this to work,  you need to remove the redundant commas from your json. So lojas.json would look like:

```
{
    "lojas": [
        {
            "cidade": "New York",
            "uf": "RS",
            "unidades": [
                {
                    "nome": "Tribeca",
                    "logradouro": "Rua Ligula Amet, 30"
                },
                {
                    "nome": "Brooklyn",
                    "logradouro": "Av. Venenatis Dapibus, 200"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "cidade": "São Paulo",
            "uf": "SP",
            "unidades": [
                {
                    "nome": "Centro",
                    "logradouro": "Av. Purus Fusce, 1003"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "cidade": "Rio de Janeiro",
            "uf": "RJ",
            "unidades": [
                {
                    "nome": "Copacabana",
                    "logradouro": "Rua Malesuada, 120"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```